# Make number grow with jQuery using same amount of time for every number

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

My goal is to perform a jQuery script that'll make any number visually grow from zero until its value with `setInterval()`.

Here's what I came up with:

```
$('.grow').each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        var max = parseInt($el.text().replace(/\s/g, ''));
        var refresh = 5;
        var start = 0;
        var step = 1;
        var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            start += step;
            $el.text(start);
            if(start >= max)
                clearInterval(interval);
        }, refresh);
    });
```

My problem is I have numbers ranging from a few hundreds to several hundreds thousands. With this script, bigger number take more time to reach their value.

My goal is to make any number, regardless of its goal value, take the same amount of time to reach it. I sense that I should divide the number by the number of seconds I want the animation to run and then, set the result as the interval step?

I'm inquiring but still seeking for help :)

Thanks.

Comment: I finally recommend using counterUp jQuery plugin : https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.grow').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var max = parseInt($el.text().replace(/\s/g, ''));
    var duration = 1000; // shared duration of all elements' animation
    var refresh = 5;
    var frames = duration / refresh; // number of frames (steps)
    var start = 0;
    var step = Math.max(Math.round(max / frames), 1); // step should be >= 1
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        if(start + step < max) {
            start += step;
        }
        else {
            start = max;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        $el.text(start);
    }, refresh);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solution make final incremented number reach the exact actual number. I'm about to accept your answer as the best suitable for my question. I'm still facing one last issue however, how can I make the final number thousands separated with spaces (at the end or during the animation, doesn't matter) ? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: _how can I make the final number thousands separated with spaces_ This is another question not related to your original post

Comment: Fair enough, I'll enquiry on my own.

Comment: @Steve You could ask for this on SO but in separated question. _BTW:_ You could upvote my answer as well if it solve your problem

Comment: Done. I've found out the script (with `refresh` set to `5`) doesn't work with number below `100` (number doesn't animate and stays at `0`). Any idea why?

Comment: @Steve That's because `step` in such cases become `< 1` and casted to `0`. See the fix for this in updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer (syntax error: check the double closing bracket on `Math.round` though).

Answer (score 0):

This should work I suppose,

```
$('.grow').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var max = parseInt($el.text().replace(/\s/g, ''));

    var start = 0;
    var refresh = 5; 
    var totalSteps = 10;
    var step = max/totalSteps;

    function calculate(){
        start += step;
        $el.text(Math.round(start));
        if(start < max){
            setTimeout(function() {
                calculate();
            }, refresh);
        }  
    }
    calculate();
});
```

This will always finish in 100 steps. I.e. 100*refresh = 100*5 = 500 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however this option make final number not to match the actual number. The step should always be `1` as the `clearInterval()` must make it stop when it reaches the exact final number.

Comment: @Steve Since you have `if(start >= max)` it doesn't need to be exact. If it exceeds i.e. `start` is bigger than `max`, this ends like you wanted

Comment: Although you have picked the answer, I am editing my answer to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. Which means you don't have to clear it. It just stops the loop on the max value.